# Jest - after how much time does the promise resolve in mock?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a jest test, where i am mocking axios get implementation.

As i render my component, it sends out a api call.

I need to test that a spinner appears as we make the call.
I need to test that the spinner disappears after the call is completed.

How do i know when the mock promise resolves?

```
axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({
data:{ query_scores: someData },
}));

const { queryByTestId, getByText } = renderWithRouter(
    <MyComponent />,
  );

  expect(queryByTestId('spinner')).not.toBeNull();
```

how can i be sure that the promise has not already been resolved by the time the `not.toBeNull` is called ?

Note: I am using react testing library, but the question is more related to the timing of mock promise resolve in general.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous it isn't so much a time delay on when a promise will return but the fact that you need to return a Promise from your test and Jest will wait for that Promise to return (however long that is).

```
test('the data is peanut butter', () => {
  return fetchData().then(data => {
  expect(data).toBe('peanut butter');
  });
});
```

In your case, according to jest.io, (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html) you would return the values using:

```
axios.get.mockResolvedValue(resp);
```

and then test against that

```
return Users.all().then(resp => expect(resp.data).toEqual(users));
```

If you want to add a time delay to your Promise, you can do so using setTimeout to control the return

```
const getData = async () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
     setTimeout(resolve, 1000);  //added arbitrary delay
   });
 };
```

Then if you call the getData function using await, you can test a before and after response to see if the spinner shows and goes away as expected

```
expect(queryByTestId('spinner')).not.toBeNull(); //expect spinner on render
await getData();
expect(queryByTestId('spinner')).toBeNull();  //expect no spinner on data returned
```

Comment: This is currently mock code, I hope to have time to fully test it later today against some of my own code base.

Comment: Make sure to use `jest.useFakeTimers()` if you use setTimeout with resolve so your test doesn't take an unnecessary second longer to run